# Connecting to MS SQL server from Windows Embedded CE 6.0

Tags: c#

Connecting to MS SQL server and from Windows Embedded CE 6.0

I am creating a scanning device application and that device has runs on Windows Embedded CE 6.0 operating system.

What is the best way to communicate connect to MS SQL server and within Windows Embedded CE 6.0?